Is a Tempest cleric playable?
I am planning to run an adventure with a new group, using the 2024 rules, and all subclasses are open to pick for the players. Legacy subclasses from the 2014 PHB and the Everything that have not been replaced can still be used. However, Wizard's guidance is that you now get all the subclass features you normally would get at first and second level at third level.
Unless I am mistaken, you do not get the benefits of the new cleric class when playing a legacy cleric, because you are playing a legacy cleric, so you use the legacy cleric class and subclass. Apart from that change of moving the subclassed to third level, you get everything based on the legacy cleric class and subclass. You get no Divine Order on level one with its improved armor options or spellcasting, and you get no Divine Spark channel divinity at level two, to restore hit points or harm opponents.
If that is the case, the change of moving the subclass to third level weakens these subclasses compared to how they worked before. For example for a Tempest cleric, at first level you do not get access to your "always prepared" domain spells (which only get through that subclass, as both fog cloud and thunderwave are not on the cleric list), you don't get proficiency with martial weapons and heavy armor, you cannot rebuke attackers with Wreath of the Storm, and at second level you cannot opt to deal maxium damage with your Channel Divinity. That's a lot you forgo.
That leaves you weaker than the new cleric classes.
It's commonly accepted that the game is the most deadly in the first and second level: you have preciously few hit points, so a single unlucky hit or two can take you out. There also is not yet enough access to magic that can revive a character, nor do the characters have the funds to purchase such services, should they be available at all.
Given this backdrop, has anyone already had experience playing a tempest cleric with the 2024 rules starting at level 1? How did they compare to the new 2024 classes, could they still hold their own, or was it very clear that they are a weak choice?
(I am really interested in any such subclass, including wizards, other cleric domains, warlocks etc.; but this might make the question too broad to ask around here. If you do have a great answer for another subclass, and nobody has answered here so far, I'll be happy to change the question to that class).

This question isn't actually about tempest cleric, since everything you say is true for all clerics. You're worried about level 1 and 2 where you don't have subclass. I'm not very familiar with the 2024 ruleset yet, but I would be very surprised if a whole class wasn't playable at level 1 and 2.

I agree with @JoakimM.H. — I don't see how the fact that someone is planning to become a Tempest at 3rd level has any effect on the survival at levels 1 and 2. Can you elaborate on that?

@Mołot One thing that might be specific for Tempest (and some others) clerics is heavy armor proficiency - dumping Dex is punished a lot if you only gain proficiency at 3rd level. But otherwise I agree, 2024 classes are designed with the fact you get subclass only at 3rd level in mind, and using 2014 subclasses does not make them any weaker at levels 1 and 2.

@molot: The tempest cleric is a legacy class, so what happens is that the features you normally get at 1st and 2nd get delayed until third while you get 0 benefit of the new cleric for the first 2 levels. The new clerics compensate for this with other general benefits like Divine Order, or more Channnel Divinity options, but the legacy classes I think do not get them. That leaves you with very few features in those crucial first levels. I am just wondering if that is still viable to try. Does that help address your question?

@JoakimM.H. Yes, what I am asking is true for all subclasses that have features on level 1 or 2 that are legacy, but I am not asking that question, as I do not think there will be someone that has played all of them. And I am asking for an experience-based answer, not a theoretical investigation (which also would likely get closed as "too broad"), so I am limiting this to just one subclass, the Tempest cleric. I might change it to another one, but I am on purpose not asking about all of them.

"but the legacy classes I think do not get them" - then include that within the question please :) Preferably with the source of that thought. In a very prominent way so it doesn't get lost in the wall of text.

@Mołot aleady did. I can bold it if you want?

It still doesn't make sense. At level 1 and 2, you have all the same features as any other cleric. You don't lose features because you're planning on taking a legacy subclass at level 3. If you're talking about using the 2014 cleric, and not just the subclass, in a 2024 game, that's different. A 2014 cleric gets their subclass features at level 1 and 2 even if the rest of the game is 2024.

@JoakimM.H. Yes, I think I misunderstood how it works to use a legacy subclass. I thought you just use the old class and subclass, all legacy, with only moving the subclass features to level 3. If you use the current cleric class, then of course you wouldn't be weaker. I am a bit puzzled by all the downvotes on the question, if I was misunderstanding this, it seems it is a valid question that others also can get wrong, and is useful to answer.

This question is similar to: When playing a legacy subclass from 2014, at what level do you gain your subclass features?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@ValhallaGH Yes, I know, I cite that question (which is mine, too). This question assumes that you only get the subclass at 3rd level. It also (I guess, erronously, although it is not clear to me entirely) assumes you use the normal 2014 cleric class when you play a 2014 legacy cleric, and hence would miss out on the new replecement features for 1st and 2nd level IF you only get the subclass features at thrid.

Hi @NobodytheHobgoblin. I'm not sure that changing the question to suit the answers depending on what classes/subclasses is going to be helfpul.

@NobodytheHobgoblin I know that is your question. And it is the same question you asked here, because this question leaves out your false assumption that a 2024 campaign would have a character using a 2014 class. That false assumption is the difference between the two questions, and it is not present in this question.

Any 2024 Cleric on Levels 1 & 2 plays the same
When using the 2024 ruleset any class, including the cleric, gets their subclass at level 3. This is indeed a change from the level 1 subclass in the old version. But this isn't something specific to the Tempest Domain, nor to any of the legacy subclasses, as that is true for the new subclasses in the 2024 PHB aswell.  Or in other words: Your subclass choice does not matter when your are level  1 or 2, you haven't chosen it yet. A Level 1 or 2 Cleric is not and cannot be a "Tempest Cleric" in the 2024 rules, that is level 3+ only.
You might have a subclass in mind that you want to choose, which can be legacy or not, but that has no effect on the capabilities of your Character before they reach level 3. You might even choose a completely different one, than you initially planned, once you finally reach level 3, as you might have gotten to know your character better, after playing it for those 2 levels.
I am unsure where your confusion about not getting Divine Order or Divine Spark comes from. When you play a Cleric in the 2024 rules you just create your character at level 1, get all the level 1 features of the base class from the 2024 PHB, then you level up to level 2 and get those features and then when you reach level 3, choose a subclass and gain its benefits. Nothing changes about your core class features, if you then choose a legacy subclass or had one in mind at earlier levels.

So you suggest they get to pick a divine order and then still keep the heavy armour proficiency at level 3? Effectively letting them get both divine order choices?

@SeriousBri The official Statement about legacy subclass features by Jeremy Crawford is found in this answer with the cleric being used as an example. Meaning this is RAW, until the designers issue a statement that those specific legacy subclass features shouldn't be gained by 2024 characters. It surely would not be a bad house rule to replace the bonus proficiencies with Divine Order or make the player choose between them. We also might see updated versions of those other subclasses in future 2024 books negating the issue entirely.

Thanks for writing a solid answer.
